# Text with icon top right

Tags: html, css

I have two divs one contain text and another contain button,

Here is what I wnat to have:

1.[image]

2. [image]

```css
.stalin::after {
   content: '';
   background-image: url('https://thumb.ibb.co/e3WZQU/Ellipse_2.png');
   position: absolute;
 }
.trump:after{
   content: '';
   background-image: url('https://thumb.ibb.co/d4BOKp/Ellipse_3.png');
   position: absolute;
}
.marketing-primary{
   color:black;
   font-family: Roboto Regular;
   width: 373px;
   height: 92px;
   background-color:white ;
}
```

```html
<div class="stalin">
  <p>Germany is dying slowly</p>
</div>
<div class="trump">
  <button type="button" class="marketing-primary">Dowiedz się wiecej</button>
</div>
```

I tried different aproach nothing is working? any idea how to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll want to do is give each of your `:after` pseudo-elements a `width` and `height` that reflects the circles' width and height. This is `38px` and `48px` respectively.

Instead of `position: absolute`, you'll actually want `position: relative`, and to make use of `float` to position the `:after` next to their respective elements. You'll also want `float: left` on the main two elements themselves (`.stalin` and `.trump`). As you're floating the elements, you'll need to also add `clear: left` to `.trump` to drop it back to the next line.

Also, note that you'll actually want to set your rules for `.stalin`'s pseudo-element on `.stalin p:after`, rather than `.stalin:after`.

From here it's just a matter of making use of `margin` to control the offsets of `:after`, and adding a negative `z-index` on `.trump:after` to position it **behind** the respective element.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
.stalin {
  float: left;
}

.stalin p::after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://thumb.ibb.co/e3WZQU/Ellipse_2.png');
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.trump {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}

.trump:after {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://thumb.ibb.co/d4BOKp/Ellipse_3.png');
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-left: -24px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.marketing-primary {
  color: black;
  font-family: Roboto Regular;
  width: 373px;
  height: 92px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="stalin">
  <p>Germany is dying slowly</p>
</div>

<div class="trump">
  <button type="button" class="marketing-primary">Dowiedz się wiecej</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.marketing-primary{
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:#fff;
  border:none;
  color:#000;
  outline:none;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  font-family: Roboto Regular;
}

.marketing-primary:after{
  content:'';
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:absolute;
  right:-10px;
  bottom:-50px;
  z-index:-1;
}

.stalin p{
  font-family: Roboto Regular;
  position:relative;
  display:table;
}

.stalin p:after{
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:1px solid blue;
  top:-5px;
  right:-20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="stalin">
  <p>Germany is dying slowly</p>
</div>

<span style="position:relative;">
<button class="marketing-primary">Dowiedz się wiecej</button>
</span>
```